# Combine Tifs and upload to Mapbox

Tags: geotiff-tiff, mapbox

I'm trying to get satellite data from Hurricane Irma to asses damage. I tried the Landsat 8 sources but they don't produce tiles that can zoom close. I found better images from NOAA which are downloadable here:

https://storms.ngs.noaa.gov/storms/irma/index.html

My issue though is that there are many tif files that I need to get into Mapbox to create a layer. Is there a way to combine these and then upload them to Mapbox?

Here is the gdal info for one of the tifs.:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: 20170911aC0813730w243600n.tif
Size is 18702, 18702
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (-81.625100000000003,24.600100000000001)
Pixel Size = (0.000001347449471,-0.000001347449471)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Point
  TIFFTAG_DOCUMENTNAME=*
  TIFFTAG_MAXSAMPLEVALUE=0
  TIFFTAG_MINSAMPLEVALUE=1
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=1 (unitless)
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=0
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=0
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=JPEG
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( -81.6251000,  24.6001000) ( 81d37'30.36"W, 24d36' 0.36"N)
Lower Left  ( -81.6251000,  24.5749000) ( 81d37'30.36"W, 24d34'29.64"N)
Upper Right ( -81.5999000,  24.6001000) ( 81d35'59.64"W, 24d36' 0.36"N)
Lower Right ( -81.5999000,  24.5749000) ( 81d35'59.64"W, 24d34'29.64"N)
Center      ( -81.6125000,  24.5875000) ( 81d36'45.00"W, 24d35'15.00"N)
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 2 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 3 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 4 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
```

Comment: [gdal_merge](http://gdal.org/gdal_merge.html) or [gdalwarp](http://gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) should do the trick. 
Use the latter if the input datasets have different reference systems

Comment: Thanks. Just found the gdal_merge that's in QGIS. Only problem is that the resulting file is 150 GB and Mapbox's limit is 10GB.